# lookahead regex in nginx location

Tags: regex, nginx, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to match **/category/anything**, except **/category/paid** in nginx location.

I have the following regex, but it's not working. Google tells me that I can use lookahead in nginx. Am I doing something wrong?

```
location ^/category(?!/paid)/ {

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You either need a slash before it or an escaped slash.

```
location ~ (category/(?!paid)) { .. }
location ~ (category\/(?!paid)) { .. }
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks! one more question..looks like my regex doesn't match /category/paid-test. I've added $ at the end, but it still doesn't match. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Maybe something like `category/(?:paid(?=-)|(?!paid))`

Comment: I dont understand what's the difference between `^/category(?!/paid)/` and `(category/(?!paid))` both should be equivalent and work for the example (match /category/anything, except /category/paid). What am I missing there?

Comment: this (category/(?!paid))  not matches paid prefix not a directory only. these are bad: 
category/paid21398410  category/paid/